# Rating control in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, rating

I am trying to incorporate a rating control in my WPF app but the projects I find are event-driven with events in the code-behind. As I am using MVVM as a design pattern I don't want to mess in any way with code behind as my rating data is coming from a View Model. What should I do? Are there any rating controls that do not require to write code behind? Or is there another solution?
Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Do you have an example of the ratings control your are trying to incorporate?  Not knowing what this control is makes it hard to suggest how to interact with it.  Seems like a ratings control would have buttons and such that should be easy to hook up to the view model via the command pattern.  ratings values as properties , etc

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not writing application logic in your code behind, you should not be affraid of interacting with controls in it. Treat both your XAML and code behind as single thing - complementary parts of single View layer. Sometimes controls require you to interact with them via code behind and there is nothing wroing about it, even in MVVM.

Comment: It is not that I have fear interacting with the code behind - I just don't know how to implement in a good way an update of ViewModel's value into the User Control (the rating control) I just didn't make this (View Model -> Code behind -> UI interaction) so far and because of that want to interact with the user control and the value it should show via binding of the ViewModel's value.

Comment: When something changes in UserControl which causes an event occurance, you can simply access ViewModel from CodeBehind and change value in ViewModel, eg.: (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).ChangeValue(...); If you need more help with specific control, please ask a new question with some sample code you have written.